# react native mongodb findOne return nothing

Tags: mongodb, react-native

```
database = new Datastore({filename: db, autoload: true});
database.findOne({_id: set}, (err, doc) => {

    ....
});
```

Sometimes return function never callback

and
It only works after reinstalling the app

Its like something wrong with closing database

Comment: Please post more information. What have you tried? Is the err object being populated? Do you some errors in the logs? (Native logs for example)

Comment: after calling findOne nothing return no err no doc nothing, no logs